# Visualization Marker + Serializable

Tags: ros, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am trying to write visualization markers (import visualization_msgs.Marker) onto a file however I get an error - and I believe the error is because Marker does not implement Serializable.

Is there any way of getting around this :/?

Thank you,
really appreciate it

P.S. im trying to store the markers onto a file and then use the markers for later

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52209/visualization-marker-+--serializable/) by [JustARandomGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3963/justarandomguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-01-14**:
How are you trying to serialize your markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean with "implements serializable"? The Marker type is of course serializable. All ROS message types are serializable.
Here an example:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest("visualization_msgs")
import visualization_msgs.msg
m=visualization_msgs.msg.Marker()
a=str(m)

In [55]: a
Out[55]: "header: \n  seq: 0\n  stamp: \n    secs: 0\n    nsecs: 0\n  frame_id: ''\nns: ad\nid: 0\ntype: 0\naction: 0\npose: \n  position: \n    x: 0.0\n    y: 0.0\n    z: 0.0\n  orientation: \n    x: 0.0\n    y: 0.0\n    z: 0.0\n    w: 0.0\nscale: \n  x: 0.0\n  y: 0.0\n  z: 0.0\ncolor: \n  r: 0.0\n  g: 0.0\n  b: 0.0\n  a: 0.0\nlifetime: \n  secs: 0\n  nsecs: 0\nframe_locked: False\npoints: []\ncolors: []\ntext: asdfadf\nmesh_resource: adfa\nmesh_use_embedded_materials: False"
```

Here the message has been serialized in the yaml format and stored a string variable. You can also use the methods the methods "Marker.serialize" and "Marker.serialize_numpy" in conjunction with the io.StringIO class

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1